# Turn off calculations while writing to excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, performance, openpyxl

I am currently using openpyxl to write to an already existing excel file. I know this is not the most time efficient library for this purpose, but the problem I am facing lies elsewhere I reckon.

When I add a specific dataframe to an existing excel spreadsheet, while the whole excel file does not contain any (excel-) formulas, it takes less than a second to finish writing to the file.

However if I use the exact same code to write to an excel file of similar size, which contains some tabs with calculated cells, it easily takes more than 10 minutes to finish.

Any ideas how to speed up the writing process in this case? I guess it takes so long because all the calculated cells are recalculated many times, maybe this can be prevented somehow...

code excerpt that I am using (don't think it matters though):

```
book = load_workbook(file_name)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I didn’t think openpyxl ever starts the Excel application: it just replicates the file format. Hence I am not sure any calculation actually happens? Perhaps you are adding rows or columns which require the engine to change the references in the formula, to maintain the integrity of the workbook?

Comment: @DS_London thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it even takes this long, when I add a new spreadsheet to the file (which should not have any connection to the rest of the file)

Comment: Openpyxl never does anything with formulae so that cannot be the reason for any performance issues.

Comment: @CharlieClark any suggestions how to improve performance anyways?

Comment: Not without the files, no.